# how to fire a controller method from another controller or directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

What I need is to show some values automatically when I process some data on another controller, but how can I fire my `$scope.setOnController1` function on `controller1` when the `controller2` have ended to process my data automatically. JS FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/b2fCE/228/

Here is `HTML` the code

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController1">
        <button ng-click="setOnController1()">Force values(SECOND)</button><br/>
        <ul>
            <li><b>myController1</b> (values won't change)</li>
            <li>{{stringValue}}</li>
            <li>{{objectValue}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>    
    <div ng-controller="myController2">
        <ul>
            <li><b>myController2</b> (values will change when Set Values is clicked or when 2-way binding textbox is modified)</li>
            <li>{{stringValue()}}</li>
            <li>{{objectValue.data}}</li>
        </ul>
        <input type="text" ng-model="newValue"></input>
        <button ng-click="setString(newValue)">Set Values(FIRST)</button><br/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="objectValue.data"></input>2-way binding to objectValue
    </div>
</div>
```

And JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.service('sharedProperties', function() {
    var stringValue = 'test string value';
    var objectValue = {
        data: 'test object value'
    };

    return {
        getString: function() {
            return stringValue;
        },
        setString: function(value) {
            stringValue = value;
        },
        getObject: function() {
            return objectValue;
        }
    }
});

app.controller('myController1', function($scope, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.setOnController1 = function(sharedPoperties){
    $scope.stringValue = sharedProperties.getString();
    $scope.objectValue = sharedProperties.getObject().data;
    }
});

app.controller('myController2', function($scope, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.stringValue = sharedProperties.getString;
    $scope.objectValue = sharedProperties.getObject();
    $scope.setString = function(newValue) {
        $scope.objectValue.data = newValue;
        sharedProperties.setString(newValue);
    //some code to set values on screen at controller1
    };

});
```

Here is the JS FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/b2fCE/228/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple different ways.  One, you can broadcast an event on Controller2 and listen for the event on Controller1 (like tymeJV suggests).  You need to broadcast and listen on the $rootScope.

```
app.controller('myController2', function($rootScope, $scope, sharedProperties) {
  $scope.stringValue = sharedProperties.getString;
  $scope.objectValue = sharedProperties.getObject();
  $scope.setString = function(newValue) {
    $scope.objectValue.data = newValue;
    sharedProperties.setString(newValue);
    //some code to set values on screen at controller1
    $rootScope.$broadcast("myEvent");
  };


app.controller('myController1', function($rootScope, $scope, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.setOnController1 = function(sharedPoperties){
        $scope.stringValue = sharedProperties.getString();
        $scope.objectValue = sharedProperties.getObject().data;
    }
    $rootScope.$on("myEvent", function() {
        $scope.setOnController1(sharedProperties);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jerrade/7TFL5/1/) demo

Similarly, you can setup a $watch on Controller1 to watch the value in your service.

```
app.controller('myController1', function($rootScope, $scope, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.setOnController1 = function(sharedPoperties){
        $scope.stringValue = sharedProperties.getString();
        $scope.objectValue = sharedProperties.getObject().data;
    }
    $scope.$watch(function(){return sharedProperties.getString()}, function(newValue, oldValue){
        $scope.setOnController1(sharedProperties);
    });

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jerrade/A2Rcn/) demo

Comment: Thanks, I guess `$watch` is better in this case because I´m using a service

Answer (score 0):

Use `$broadcast` and `$on`

Controller 1:

```
$scope.$broadcast("myEvent");
```

Controller 2:

```
$scope.$on("myEvent", function() {
    console.log("Lets go!");
});
```

If you need to share data in between, use a shared service.

Comment: I think he already is using a shared service (named `sharedProperties` actually)

Comment: Yes I can read an show the values at `controller1` using the service but In need to do this automatically when `controller2` ends to process it.