# Passing a var between 2 controllers via a service in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 controllers like the following:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, GCs, GCDetails ) {
    $scope.getData = function(id)
    {
        GCs.get(id)
        .success(function(data){
            console.log(data); // it is getting the data correctly here.

            // I want to pass the data to 'GCDetailCtrl' controller
            GCDetails = data;
        });
    };
})

.controller('GCDetailCtrl', function($scope, GCs) {
     console.log(GCDetails); // I am getting an empty object
     $scope.itemDetails = GCDetails; //nothing in it
})
```

I tried many methods and saw many threads on stackoverflow but I couldn't figure out what is the problem.

My service is like the following:

```
.service('GCDetails', function () {
    return {};
});
```

I feel like my service is wrong because I am always returning an empty object. any help please? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're not assigning the value in service. You need to store `ajax` response in service and then call it in another controller. Do it in below way

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, GCs, GCDetails ) {
    $scope.getData = function(id)
    {
        GCs.get(id)
        .then(function(data){
            console.log(data); // it is getting the data correctly here.

            // I want to pass the data to 'GCDetailCtrl' controller
            GCDetails.myObject = data; // assign data in service's object
        });
    };
})
```

And your service should be

```
.service('GCDetails', function () {
    this.myObject = {};
    var self = this; 
    this.callAFunction = function() {
       return self.myObject ;
    };
 });
```

And use this service's object where you want as below

```
.controller('GCDetailCtrl', function($scope, GCs, GCDetails) {
     $scope.itemDetails = GCDetails.callAFunction();
     console.log($scope.itemDetails); //You will get the data
})
```

Comment: I am getting an empty object {}

Comment: Are you sure you're getting data in get request

Comment: of course .. the console.log is showing me that there is a json array

Comment: I think I know the reason.. when you try to console.log(data) and console.log($scope.GCDetails.myObject).. it is giving you an empty object before and then the object that holds the data in it

Comment: GCs is a factory that calls the get method request via $http

Comment: It is returning an empty object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82325/discussion-between-vineet-and-riad).

Answer (score 0):

your service must set the object first, before you attempt to fetch the updated object.

so it should look something like this

```
.service('GCDetails', function(){
  var self = this;
  self.myObject = {};

  self.setObject = function (val) {
    self.myObject = val;
  };

  self.getObject = function() {
    return self.myObject;
  };
});
```

why did i assign this to self? to avoid collision, when you are calling getObject or setObject, it does not know which self are you calling.

Comment: I did not change anything in my controller. I just changed the service as you suggested

Comment: i don't know what you are trying to do, but here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cjs5nu3o/1/

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to make http calls from controllers. You can make a service return a function with your http call. What I would suggest is:

```
app.factory('GCdetails', function($http){
    return {
        data:{},
        setData:function(data){
          this.data=data;
        },
        get : function(params){
            return $http.get(id, {
                params : params
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And now from the controllers update the data:

```
app.controller('DashCtrl',function($scope,GCdetails){
    GCdetails.get().success(function(data){
      GCdetails.setData(data);
    });
});

app.controller('GCdetailsController',function($scope,GCdetails){
    $scope.itemDetails=GCdetails.data;
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, and is how I always use services to pass data around:

```
.service('GCDetails', function() {

  var myObj = {};

  this.setObject = function (val) {
    myObj = val;
  };

  this.getObject = function() {
    return myObj;
  };
});
```

Also in your controller make sure that you call `GCDetails.setObject(yourvalue)` from your controller so it actually have a value when you call `GCDetails.getObject()`.

Comment: @Riad Make sure you actually set a value from the controller before you try and get the data.